# "Lesson" vs "unit" in books

Tags: differences, nouns

I am so confused about *unit* and *lesson* in books. I looked up Longman Dictionary and it said "a part of book". What's the difference between them in this case?

Comment: Hello Peter PAD, there are no semantic differences in the context you referred to; generally that is an editor choice.

Comment: Units in textbooks may contain many lessons, or each lesson may be a separate unit. Depends on the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A unit is a part of something larger, while a lesson is when you are taught about something. They mean different things on their own, but in the context of a book they are just various names for sections.